# selective `for` loop for an R function: `for` loop Or `Vectorize`

Tags: r, function, for-loop, vectorization

I have a small `R` function called `ab`. I'm trying to allow user of the function to provide a `vector` for either argument `m` or `s` (not both).

**Question:**
I'm wondering how should I set up my `for` loop so that I can selectively loop either over `m` or `s` based on user's choice? [is it better to use `Vectorize` here?]

Here is my R code with no success:

```
ab = function(m, s, lo = -Inf, hi = Inf){

loop = if(length(m) > 1) length(m) else length(s)

for(i in 1:loop){

p = function(x) dnorm(x, m[i], s[i])  # [i] should be either for `m` or `s` but what can I do here to have [i] be selectively chosen?
f = function(x) p(x)/integrate(p, lo, hi)[[1]]
curve(f, -3, 3, add = i!= 1, col = i)
    }
}
# Example of use:
ab(m = c(0, .5), s = 1) # Error in integrate(p, lo, hi) : non-finite function value
```

Comment: How about `z <- if (missing(m)) s else m`, and then use `z` from then on?

Comment: @r2evans, I see your point, but so, the problem is here: `p = function(x) dnorm(x, m[i], s[i]) `, where should `[i]` go to?  Next to `s` or `m`. If we are looping over `s` then we only need one `[i]` next to `s` but no `[i]` after `m`. So right now, with two `[i]`s next to `m` and `s` the function doesn't know over what to do the looping?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see ... stby ...

Comment: Not really ... see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly appreciate the answer by our colleague `@r2evans`, but I think this problem might have a bit simpler solution (i.e., one line of `if` syntax):

```
ab = function(m, s, lo = -Inf, hi = Inf){

loop = if(length(m) > 1) length(m) else length(s)

p = if(length(m) > 1) function(x) dnorm(x, m[i], s) else function(x) dnorm(x, m, s[i])

for(i in 1:loop){
f = function(x) p(x)/integrate(p, lo, hi)[[1]]
curve(f, -3, 3, add = i!= 1, col = i)
 }
}
# Example of use:
ab(m = c(0, 1), 1)
#Example of use:
ab(m = 0, c(1, 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One thought:

```
ab <- function(m, s, lo = -Inf, hi = Inf) {
  if (length(m) > 1) {
    if (length(s) > 1) {
      warning("'m' and 's' are both long, truncating 's'")
    }
    s <- rep(s[1], length(m))
  } else {
    m <- rep(m, length(s))
  }
  # something else here ...
}
```

All this is doing is ensuring both variables are the same length, forcing one to be the unchanging variable. (I think that's what you are trying to do ...)

I don't think you can efficiently vectorize the basic calculations, since (among other things) `integrate` really needs to deal with one problem at a time. To improve anything, I might suggest doing all of the calculation and returning all values into a single list. From there, it's rather straight-forward to plot the lines individually:

```
ab <- function(m, s, lo = -Inf, hi = Inf,
               xrange = c(-3, 3), n = 50) {
  if (length(m) > 1) {
    if (length(s) > 1) {
      warning("'m' and 's' are both long, truncating 's'")
    }
    s <- rep(s[1], length(m))
  } else {
    m <- rep(m, length(s))
  }
  xs <- seq(xrange[1], xrange[2], length = n)
  out <- mapply(function(a,b) {
    p = function(x) dnorm(x, a, b)
    f = function(x) p(x) / integrate(p, lo, hi)[[1]]
    list(x = xs, y = sapply(xs, f))
  }, m, s, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  out
}
ret <- ab(m = c(0, .5), s = 1)
str(ret)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ x: num [1:50] -3 -2.88 -2.76 -2.63 -2.51 ...
#   ..$ y: num [1:50] 0.00443 0.00635 0.00897 0.01247 0.01709 ...
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ x: num [1:50] -3 -2.88 -2.76 -2.63 -2.51 ...
#   ..$ y: num [1:50] 0.000873 0.00133 0.001996 0.002951 0.004298 ...
```

From here, you should be able to plot trivially all at once:

```
yrange <- c(0, max(sapply(ret, `[[`, "y")))
plot(0, type = 'n', xlim = c(-3,3), ylim = yrange,
     ylab = "Density", xlab = "Z")
ign <- mapply(function(d,i) lines(y~x, data=d, col=i),
              ret, seq_along(ret))
```

[image: sample dnorm curves]

Separating the *calculation* portion from the *plotting* portion typically benefits (IMHO) calculation speed, reproduction of plots without recalculation, and organization of code.

Comment: Thank you so much! for all your time and expertise on this. I have upvoted your answer. If you don't mind I will wait to see if there might be another answer that could better fit my purpose. Once I highly appreciate your response.